# Postgresql, объеденить последовательные числа через тире, наименьшее тире наибольшее

Tags: sql, postgresql, оконные-функции

[image: Столбец №3 сгруппирован по столбцу №1 и столбцу №2. На дубликаты не нужно обращать внимание их можно все убрать.]

Нужно сделать так чтобы в столбце №3, который сгруппирован по столбцу №1 и столбцу №2. Числа, которые идут по порядку были записаны в сокращенной форме, а именно, "1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12" -> "1-5, 9-12" и так далее.
Пробовал функции lag и lead, то есть делать дополнительные столбцы, в которых числа получались смещены относительно столбца nomkvr, но я не знаю как и что можно с их помощью дальше рассчитать.
И вообще не знаю, на сколько это реально сделать в одном лишь postgresql.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Пример объединения:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (9), (10), (11), (12), (20);
>
> WITH 
> cte1 AS ( SELECT id, id - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) grp
>           FROM test ),
> cte2 AS ( SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(id) < MAX(id)
>                       THEN MIN(id)::text || '-' || MAX(id)::text
>                       ELSE MIN(id)::text
>                       END single_range
>           FROM cte1 
>           GROUP BY grp
>           ORDER BY grp )
> SELECT STRING_AGG(single_range, ', ') ranges_list
> FROM cte2;
> ```
>
> ```
> | ranges_list   |
> | :------------ |
> | 1-5, 9-12, 20 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f4a54709dc5d6cad1bfb59f415a918ac)*